# What do the different stat points give?

Tags: monster-clicker

After leveling up, I can put a stat point in either STR, AGI, or INT.  What do each of these do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- STR add 0.2% EXP multiplier
- INT add 0.2 % GOLD multiplier
- AGI add 0.5 gold and exp per click and 0.5% gold and exp per click

Source:  The Instructions tab on the [Kongregate page](http://www.kongregate.com/games/BJ_Interactive/monster-clicker)

Comment: Helpful.  The link I was using didn't have those instructions.